# Installed openssl-dev on linux, but opensslv.h missing

Tags: linux-kernel, openssl

That file opensslv.h is requested by "make modules bzImage" when trying to compile a new kernel. I had previously done

```
$ sudo apt-get install update and
$ sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev
$ openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
```

with no problems reported;

This is the error msg given by make modules bzImage after a few seconds:

```
(...)
HOSTCC  scripts/sign-file
scripts/sign-file.c:23:30: fatal error: openssl/opensslv.h: No such file   or directory
compilation terminated.
scripts/Makefile.host:91: recipe for target 'scripts/sign-file' failed
make[1]: *** [scripts/sign-file] Error 1
Makefile:556: recipe for target 'scripts' failed
make: *** [scripts] Error 2
```

I searched google for the error message; most answers indicate that I should install openssl-dev, which I did. I also searched here for the name of the missing file but answers were not helpful.

I am doing this on ubuntu 16.04, trying to install kernel version linux 4.4.53. Previous steps (installing libncurses5-dev, make menuconfig and make localconfig) gave no problem.

Comment: *libcurl4-openssl-dev* has almost nothing to do with *openssl-dev*. It is **not** a *openssl-dev*-like package. In Debian systems you need *libssl-dev*.

Comment: Thanks 0andriy. apt-get install openssl-dev worked six months ago, but now it is not found, so I searched for it and that's how I got to libcurl4... I'll try libssl-dev

Comment: @Jose - Its `libssl-dev`, not `openssl-dev`. If the problem persists, then please provide the relevant pieces from `config.log`. This is a *really* interesting statement: *"`opensslv.h` is requested by "make modules bzImage" when trying to compile a new kernel"*. The kernel has its own crypto, and I know its not a rip of OpenSSL.

Comment: Thanks @jww -- libssl-dev worked indeed. Further, that "make modules bzImage" is no longer needed; a simple "make" suffices. I have no idea why that file opensslv.h was requested before.